# Documentation beta broken link to Area 51

Tags: bug, status-declined, area-51, broken-link, documentation-beta

The [Documentation beta](https://docs-beta.stackexchange.com/) states:

> Warning: this site is currently in private beta for at least a few more days.
>
> To log in, you must have commited to the [Area 51 site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/lookup/docs-beta.stackexchange.com) proposal and received the invitation email. Click the invitation link in the email to log in!

The link to Area 51 is broken, because there never was any Area 51 proposal.

Comment: Agreed, this whole section should be removed in there.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Dunno, I upvoted. I guess people think that since you should not get to that page anyway (no direct link anywhere), it doesn't matter if it's broken. Nothing personal, it's pretty common here on MSE

Comment: @ShadowWizard I found a direct link in chat

Comment: That really doesn't count. I mean no official link in any page on Stack Exchange, e.g. footer, sites lists, etc. SE can't control what people post in chat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To be perfectly honest, this doesn't matter. Docs-beta is a one-off special-purpose site and our time is best spent working on the actual Documentation than fixing minute details on pages that make certain assumptions about the purpose of the site.

If we were keeping the site around, it'd be one thing. But it's going down at the end of the private beta (in a few weeks), so... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: "going down at the end of the private beta" meaning launched into public beta, or has the project failed? Sorry if obvious, I don't really follow MSO.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I suppose if it had failed, we'd be shutting it down now and not in a few weeks. ;)

Comment: OK, will take a look later at the status and bug you again if still can't find. Thanks! ;)

Answer (score 0):

That's a function of the site being in private beta mode.

I imagine that all sites have a setting that indicates what stage they are in - private beta, public beta, or graduated.

Behind this there is presumably some code that changes functionality. For private betas, it shows the typical Area 51 sign-up message, presumably with the Area 51 link populated either with a default or by another setting or an environment variable.

For sites that are private betas but aren't through the normal process, it's not worth changing the codebase just for them - so the Area 51 link is just not the right one.

Comment: "just not the right one" isn't fully right, since there is no right link. :)